# Couldn't find file 'bootstrap' in rails 4.0.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-switch

Im struck from past two days in the above issue and googled everything but could not find a solution.. So i'm trying to post this question.... I included bootstrap-switch in my application and included that in .css and .js file but im getting the error: Couldn't find file 'bootstrap'. Below is my code:

```
Gemfile:
gem 'rails', '4.0.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-switch-rails', '3.0.0'
```

Application.css

```
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require bootstrap3-switch
 *= require_tree .
```

Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-switch
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Have you included bootstrap.css in your project?

Comment: yes i did bootstrap.min.css